# show textnote if price is 0.99

Tags: jquery

I want to show a note "This is disclaimer" if the price is $0.99 using jquery. I have used following code but its not working, even it is not showing alert also.please help me out

If the price is showing up on popup using overlay then how to show following note.

```
var productpricevalue=$(".ProductPrice");
if(productpricevalue == 0.99){
//alert(productpricevalue);
//note is shown here
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first line shall be `var productpricevalue=$(".ProductPrice").text();` or `.val()`

Comment: `$(".ProductPrice")` is a jQuery object not a float. BTW, it's a [bad idea](http://floating-point-gui.de/) to compare float like you do.

Comment: @RC +1 for pointing out that comparing float like that is a bad idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var productpricevalue=$(".ProductPrice").val();
if(productpricevalue == "0.99"){
//alert(productpricevalue);
//note is shown here
}
```

Comment: @mkoryak  I have used this code but still it is not working.my product price is showing up on popup using overlay then how to show that note.

Answer (score 2):

that is not how you get a value from an input. Try:

```
var productpricevalue=$(".ProductPrice").val();
```